# Sequence of item in recursive call method using javascript / Python(same prob except syntax)

Tags: javascript, recursion

working with recursive method makes me thing about the sequence of items how they pop out from array and how they were displayed in console log, can anybody help me to understand it, here below given array will pop out in the sequence 11, 21, 13, 14 but the alert after recursive call the alert will show the value in sequence, 14, 13, 21, 11 ? Thanks in advance

```
var arr = [11, 21, 13, 14]

function reverse(arr){
    alert('in method')
    if(arr.length > 0){
    var item = arr.splice(0, 1);
    alert("item before recursive call " + item)
    reverse(arr)
    alert("item after recursive call " + item)
  }
}

reverse(arr)
```

Comment: What is your actual question here? (e.g. expected bahaviour vs. observed beviour)

Comment: here question is about the behavior of output how it getting display, irrespective how item from the array pop out from array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's due to Tail Call recursion(or tail-end recursion) and  the value of **item** is saved on the call stack. 
**In assembly**
With out Tail call :

```
 `foo:
  call B
  call A
  ret
```

Tail call elimination replaces the last two lines with a single jump instruction

```
foo:
call B
jmp  A
```

for more info you can use this link
http://www.sitepoint.com/recursion-functional-javascript/``

Comment: Thanks a lot, it short out my prob and gave me more clarity :)

Answer (score 0):

the alert does reverse cause you are calling 
reverse(arr) so the array is called out in a reversed order

Comment: Yea, but where it stores value of item and what is about the async behavior here ?